# intermittent problem occurring with a table that is only used for selection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database running on SQL Server 2008. An exception throws when any statement refers to one specific table called 'stop':

`Msg 6533, Level 16, State 48, Line 1
AppDomain mssqlsystemresource.sys[runtime].12171 was unloaded by escalation policy to ensure the consistency of your application. Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource. 
The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.`

The database performs only selections, never insert or update, so there is no problem with log. Statements refering any other table works fine.

Comment: don't want to sound silly, but this error is normally SQL Server 2005 specific...

Comment: I'm sure it's SQL Server 2008.

Comment: It happens on 2012 as well.

Answer (score 3):

STOP is a keyword in SQL Server. I suggest replacing all references to the table with **[stop]** instead of simply **stop**

Comment: +1 good spot - but I'd recommend renaming it - what a terrible table name

Comment: Agreed, although i've seen worse. Let's hope there are no dependencies to complicate a rename here :)

Comment: Ok, it's not a good name for a table, but a simple select like "select top 1 * from [stop]" stops to work. :/

Comment: The query works fine, but suddenly stops working. Then i must restart the SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I suggest posting the query in another question, unless the updated query still fails with the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CLR issue affecting memory and paging, but MS KB only mentions [SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=is%20marked%20for%20unload%20due%20to%20memory%20pressure&catalog=LCID%3d2057&mode=r&spid=2855&range=).

I'd call MS Support... you may have found genuine bug in SQL Server 2008...